# Transferring Bitmap file from a secondary Form to the main Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, bitmap

I have two Forms, **Form1** which is the main Form and **Form2** a secondary Form.
Through a Button in **Form1** I open **Form2** and I pass an Integer and a Bitmap from **Form1** to **Form2**.
In **Form2** I change the Bitmap based on what that Integer's value is.
I display the changed Bitmap in **Form2** and with a Button press I pass the changed Bitmap to **Form1** and close **Form2**.

What I am having trouble with is getting that changed Bitmap back to **Form1**. Can't seem to find a way to do this.

**In Form1**

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ReceiveData(integer); //this to pass the integer
        f2.Linear(bmp); //this to pass the Bitmap 
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**In Form 2**

```
    int integer_f2;
    internal void ReceiveData(int integer)
    {
        integer_f2 = integer;
    }

    public void Linear(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        //-- ALGORITH THAT CHANGES THE IMAGES HERE (sample for testing purposes)--
        Bitmap bmp_f2 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                // basically fill bmp2 with whatever color integer_f2 represents
                Color clr = Color.FromArgb(255, integer_f2, integer_f2, integer_f2);

                bmp_f2.SetPixel(x, y, clr);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void Button_Cancel_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Button_OK_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //-- PASS THE CHANGED BITMAP BACK TO FORM1 HERE --
        Close();
    }
```

Comment: You need  to show what you are doing with the Bitmap passed in Linear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, filled Linear with what I currently have in there. Just a small algorithm so that i can test things while i get everything else working. Sorry for not including that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form2,

```
    private class  Form2 : Form
    {
        private Bitmap _bmp;
        public Bitmap bmpResult { get; private set; } = null;
     
        public void Linear(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            //-- ALGORITHM THAT CHANGES THE BITMAP HERE --
            _bmp = bmp;
            // Do what you need to here.
        }

        private void Button_Cancel_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        }

        private void Button_OK_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmpResult = _bmp;
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

    }
```

and then in Form1,

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        using (Form2 f2 = new Form2())
        {
            f2.ReceiveData(integer); //this to pass the integer
            f2.Linear(bmp); //this to pass the Bitmap 
            if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                bmp = f2.bmpResult;
                //or do whatever you want with the result
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution worked fine. I have only one question if you are so kind as to answer. Why are we going with "using" to create f2? Is it just cleaner code or is there a more specific reason for it?

Comment: The using ensures the form is disposed once you've finished with it, which you have when  using ShowDialog().  If you weren't displaying form as Modal - i.e. using Show() that wouldn't work as you would want the form to persist even after you exit the method.

Comment: I see. I have using in some other parts of my program but I never really understood why. Thank you Jon. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to overload the `ShowDialog` method of `Form2` to accept the required arguments. Form2 should also have a public property e.g. `ChangedBitmap` that receives the result of the transform based on the integer.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2() => InitializeComponent();
    public DialogResult ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner, Bitmap bitmapIn, int integer)
    {
        // Set bitmap based on integer
        switch (integer % 2)
        {
            case 0: ChangedBitmap = transform0(bitmapIn); break;
            case 1: ChangedBitmap = transform1(bitmapIn); break;
        }
        // Call base class version
        return base.ShowDialog(owner);
    }

    private Bitmap transform0(Bitmap bitmapIn) =>
        ChangedBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxLeft.Image; // Mock result
    private Bitmap transform1(Bitmap bitmapIn) =>
        ChangedBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBoxRight.Image; // Mock result

    public Bitmap ChangedBitmap { get; private set; }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
```

[image: before]

---

`MainForm` looks at the `DialogResult` to determine whether to use `ChangedBitmap`.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    private readonly Form2 _form2 = new Form2();
    private int _testCount = 0;
    // Check the result
    private void buttonShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bitmapOut = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
        switch (_form2.ShowDialog(this, bitmapOut, _testCount))
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                // Answer to: "getting that changed Bitmap back to Form1" 
                pictureBox1.Image = _form2.ChangedBitmap;
                _testCount++;
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                break;
        }
    }
    // In MainForm.Designer.cs
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            // Modal dialog requires disposal when done.
            _form2.Dispose();
        }
        // Modal dialog requires dispose when done.
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

[image: after]

Comment: I ended up not using your solution but i still have some questions about it. Why is disposing important in this situation? And in general that snippet of code that is supposed to go to the designer of the main form I don't get. Anywhere i can go to learn more about it? Thank you for the solution by the way.

Comment: Those things are explained in detail in the Microsoft doc for [ShowDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). The reason it's designed this way is, suppose your "Form2" is the Settings for your app and has 100 different properties the user can modify. You don't want to initialize all 100 settings every time you show it, and you want the properties always accessible while the app runs, so you make it a member of the main class. So, unlike `Show/Hide`, the window resource is _not_ disposed so that it may be shown repeatedly.

Comment: This is why, in the accepted answer, the `ShowDialog` is wrapped in a `using` statement because that ensures proper disposal of the resource. This is needed because it's a brand-new instance of `Form2` every time you show it, but that's rarely a good way to go about things for the aforementioned reason.

Comment: See also [IDisposable Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0).

Comment: I'd upvote your answer but since i made an account here a few days past I cant upvote yet. I will definitely try your solution as well at some point and try to understand it. But for now I'll use the accepted one. 
Thank you very much for the solution and answering my questions as well as providing links to further expand my understanding on this matter.